# Describe positive test in gherkin language

Tags: bdd, acceptance-testing, gherkin, specifications, scenarios

We're trying to express our requirements following the specification by example approach in the gherkin language. One part of the functionality is a check that under some conditions fails and should otherwise be positive. So we have many scenarios like this:

```
 Given a <condition>         //condition changes between scenario
 When the check is performed
 Then the result is negative
```

So after describing all the conditions under which check can fail, we would need one positive scenario like:

```
Given ...                // this is what we're missing. 
When the check is performed
Then the result is positive
```

We can't come up with a good way to formulate this one. **Please note,** this is part of a generic piece of functionality that can be extended by different products, so we can't just write: 'none of the above conditions apply'

Can any of you come up with a formulation that would mean something like `Given there are no conflicting conditions`, but is more testable?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could just do

```
When the check is performed
Then it works
```

It would be much better though if the scenarios talked about what is. Say we are signing in. I'd start with

```
When I sign in
Then I should be signed in
```

and then extend that for the sad paths

```
Given my email is invalid
When I sign in
Then I should not be signed in
```

All of the above would probably need some background e.g.

```
Given I am registered.
```

You don't have to have a given for every scenario

Here is an example imlementation for the Given

```
module RegistrationStepHelper do
  def create_registered_user
    # return a user who is registered and can sign in
    ...
  def sign_in_as(user)
end
World RegistrationStepHelper

"Given I am registered" do 
   @i=create_registered_user
end

When "I sign in" do
  sign_in_as: @i
end

...
```

for a slightly expanded example [see here](https://github.com/diabolo/cuke_up/tree/master/features)

Comment: Instead of "When I sign in, Then I should be signed in" I'd use "When I submit valid credentials, Then I should be signed in", this would make the test less ambiguous. Also. I wouldn't refer to the e-mail, as from a testing perspective they are disparate entities, instead I'd just use "When I submit invalid credentials, Then I should not be signed in". Totally agree with you regarding the background.

Comment: But I can't talk about 'valid credentials'  without describing what valid means. And that's exactly the problem, valid are those who are not in conflict with the other scenarios.  @diabolist, I don't see how I could live the Given out, since that would imply the When-Then clauses are always true for any preconditions.

Comment: Valid credentials is about how you sign in. Whilst I see the point I don't think there is any need for it, when you have the feature setting the context about signing in. As I said you would need some sort of Given to set up who you are. I'll edit the answer and add an example implementation.